# Email Input and Submit button on same line?

Tags: html, css

How can I get my email input and submit button sitting next to each other on the same line?

I've tried adding: `display: inline-block` but it doesn't seem to work?

**URL:**
https://www.moneynest.co.uk/641-2/

**Code**

```
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email...*" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear signup"><button id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Send me the course!</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<hr />
```

Comment: Look at your containing divs/form. I think the width is being taken up completely by the email input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a hanging `<br>` tag that adds a blank row to your content.

e.g. > The browser tells that everything after this input field should be on a new row.

> And this "fix" for spam-bots saying that your input should be inside a `<p>` tag, I dont think that is valid.

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll" style="margin-left: 30px;">
    <p> <input value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email...*" required="" type="email">
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    </p>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value="" type="text"></div>
    <div class="clear signup"><button id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Send me the course!</button>
    </div>
    <hr>
 </div>
```

There is also a div with the id of `#mc_embed_signup` that has a `width: 300px` hardcoded. That will not allow You to get those elements on the same row without them overflowing their container.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what did you change?

Comment: After your `<input>` tag, there was a breakspace tag `<br>`

Comment: Thanks, I can't see this in my code? Perhaps Wordpress added it?

Comment: Usually, when using some rich text editors on your website, when you hit `Enter` to go on a new line, they automatically add a `<br>` tag. So this is good to keep in mind.

Comment: Also, there is some sort of layout issue which is caused by those other objects that you have in that specific container. Try setting the width of `mc_embed_signup_scroll` to something like.. 500px and see what happens. This needs a bit of rewriting I think.

Comment: There is also a hard-coded width for `#mc_embed_signup` of `300px`. Set it to `width: auto` or whatever percentage you might want it to be. Then do the rest of the manipulations with the inner objects. I've added this information to my answer above as well.

Comment: Thanks I've removed both ID's you mentioned (to stop any confliction) and updated to your code but still had no luck?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133987/discussion-between-sqnkov-and-sam-jefferies).

Answer (score 2):

Using [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is the best approache for this kind of requirements, not only because it's going to solve your problem, and also you are going to be able to forget if your device is landscape or portrait oriented.

Try this:

```css
.row-container{
  display: flex;
  row-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-container">
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email...*" required>
    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear signup"><button id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Send me the course!</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<hr />
</div>
```

Comment: He is using a custom pre-built Wordpress theme, so I don't think that these types of manipulations would do him good unless he is sure about the changes that need to be done.

Answer (score 0):

> you have input tag outside of the div here is the fix Use this code below.

```
<div>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email...*" required>
    <input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value="">
    <button id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Send me the course</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `float: left` on your input field

```css
#mce-EMAIL {
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email...*" required>
<!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear signup"><button id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Send me the course!</button>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tried this but had no luck?

Comment: If I run the code snippet it works... Does it for you?

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use `<table>`

```
<table> <th>   
 <td><input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email...*" required></td>

    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<td>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_9ccf2d2219536b32eaae3c3d1_33b662ad0d" tabindex="-1" value="">
</div>
    <div class="clear signup">
<button id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="text-uppercase btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-bottom">Send me the course!</button>
    </div>
</td></th></table>
</form>
</div>
<hr />
```